# Can it be changed with the help of if?

Tags: r, if-statement, data-science

I need to write a query in R.

In a data frame "car_1", I have a column named drivewheel.

After applying Table, I got below values

```
4wd fwd rwd 
 9  120  76
```

I found that these are misspelled.

I want all these turn to fwd.

How can I write this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following regex:

```
car_1$drivewheel <- sub("^(4|r)(wd)", "f\\2", car_1$drivewheel)
```

Explanation:

1. `^(4|r)` gets either a `"4"` or an `"r"` at the beginning as the first capture group.
2. `(wd)` is the second capture group.
3. Replace by an `"f"` and the second capture group.